# How can I make one grid column proportionately larger than another?

Tags: css, css-grid

I need to make two columns proportionally sized so that the second column is 4 times larger than the first one.

How would I do that?

```css
main{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: ???
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(50pc, auto);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the `fr` unit, like this:

```css
main{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(50pc, auto);
}
```

That will make the two columns take all the available space with the second column occupying four times as much space as the first one.